# Android-CheckBox selection Only from ListView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I was wondering if I can check items (checkbox) from ListView and have something with the selected items. But I dont want to use 'ListView.OnItemClickListener' because I have a separate functionality for clicking the list item. Something like 'CheckBox.OnClickListener' where I can grab all the list items that are checked. Any help is highly appreciated. Below is the code I am currently having, not functional though:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  ListView list;
  GoodAdapter imageAdapter;
  CheckBox cb;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  //populates the details as in imageBeanArray
    imageAdapter = new GoodAdapter(this, imageBeanArray);
    list.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                final int position, long id) {
          //does something
        }

       //throws NPE
       cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            if (cb.isSelected()) {
                checkedArray.add((ImageBean) list.getItemAtPosition(list.getSelectedItemPosition()));
            }
        }
    });
 }
```

GoodAdapter.java:
All other variables initialized

```
  public class GoodAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
      boolean[] itemChecked;
      CheckBox[] checkBoxArray;

   public GoodAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ImageBean> imageBean) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mImageBeans = imageBean;
    itemChecked=new boolean[imageBean.size()];
    checkBoxArray=new CheckBox[itemChecked.length];
   }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    if(convertView == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.good_adapter, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.docName);
        holder.imageMore = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageMore);
        holder.imageMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.checkbox=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        view.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        view = convertView;
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
        if (itemChecked[position]){
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
            mImageBeans.get(position).setSelected(true);
        }
        else
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);

    }

    ImageBean imageBean = mImageBeans.get(position);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBean.getImage(), 0, imageBean.getImage().length);
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
    holder.name.setText(imageBean.getDocName());
    if (imageBean.isMoreThanOne()!=0)
        holder.imageMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (holder.checkbox.isChecked())
                itemChecked[position] = true;
            else
                itemChecked[position] = false;
        }
    });

    checkBoxArray[position].setChecked(itemChecked[position]);
    checkBoxArray[position].setOnCheckedChangeListener(mListener);

    return view;
}

CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener mListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        itemChecked[(Integer)buttonView.getTag()] = isChecked; // get the tag so we know the row and store the status
    }
};

 private class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView name,imageMore;
     public CheckBox checkbox;
}
```

Good Adapter.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/imageList">

 <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/image_border"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        />

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/docName"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imageMore"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/more"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me.I didnt find any useful tutorials/solutions.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you can't have a listener on component of the row and a listener on the row itself if you do that one will take advantage on the other that will never be called.

Comment: I had the same doubt as you.Thank you for your response

Comment: You're welcome ;) feel free tu mark the answer as best answer and upvote it ;)